# Sign In with Google in Kotlin with firebase not working

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

It's either code or something in the Firebase console that I might have not configured but when I try to use Login With Google button, it fetches all the Google accounts logged in to the device but doesn't login and redirects to the HomeActivity.kt, i.e. homepage. I have added the SHA-1 key as well. Is this because of something that I haven't configured in the FireBase console or is it the code?

LogCat:

2024-02-06 13:12:19.773 12742-12742 ziparchive              com.example.a4you                    W  Unable to open '/data/data/com.example.a4you/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes4.dm': No such file or directory
2024-02-06 13:12:19.785 12742-12742 ziparchive              com.example.a4you                    W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~sDVy1VqoqH92Urn2U_f0-A==/com.example.a4you-35aGTBZe055q_BOX_fro7Q==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-02-06 13:12:19.786 12742-12742 ziparchive              com.example.a4you                    W  Unable to open '/data/app/~~sDVy1VqoqH92Urn2U_f0-A==/com.example.a4you-35aGTBZe055q_BOX_fro7Q==/base.dm': No such file or directory
2024-02-06 13:12:20.763 12742-12742 nativeloader            com.example.a4you                    D  Configuring clns-6 for other apk /data/app/~~sDVy1VqoqH92Urn2U_f0-A==/com.example.a4you-35aGTBZe055q_BOX_fro7Q==/base.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~sDVy1VqoqH92Urn2U_f0-A==/com.example.a4you-35aGTBZe055q_BOX_fro7Q==/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand:/data/user/0/com.example.a4you
2024-02-06 13:12:20.829 12742-12742 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.a4you                    V  Currently set values for:
2024-02-06 13:12:20.829 12742-12742 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.a4you                    V    angle_gl_driver_selection_pkgs=[]
2024-02-06 13:12:20.830 12742-12742 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.a4you                    V    angle_gl_driver_selection_values=[]
2024-02-06 13:12:20.841 12742-12742 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.a4you                    V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.example.a4you: false
2024-02-06 13:12:20.842 12742-12742 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.a4you                    V  com.example.a4you is not listed in per-application setting
2024-02-06 13:12:20.843 12742-12742 GraphicsEnvironment     com.example.a4you                    V  Neither updatable production driver nor prerelease driver is supported.
2024-02-06 13:12:20.955 12742-12742 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.a4you                    D  Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
2024-02-06 13:12:21.087 12742-12742 FirebaseApp             com.example.a4you                    I  Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
2024-02-06 13:12:21.121 12742-12742 FirebaseInitProvider    com.example.a4you                    I  FirebaseApp initialization successful
2024-02-06 13:12:21.270 12742-12771 libEGL                  com.example.a4you                    D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2024-02-06 13:12:21.277 12742-12771 libEGL                  com.example.a4you                    D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2024-02-06 13:12:21.291 12742-12771 libEGL                  com.example.a4you                    D  loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2024-02-06 13:12:21.578 12742-12742 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.a4you                    D  Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
2024-02-06 13:12:21.673 12742-12742 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.a4you                    D  Compat change id reported: 3400644; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
2024-02-06 13:12:21.891 12742-12742 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.a4you                    D  Compat change id reported: 237531167; UID 10193; state: DISABLED
2024-02-06 13:12:21.914 12742-12742 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.a4you                    W  Unknown dataspace 0
2024-02-06 13:12:21.933 12742-12742 Choreographer           com.example.a4you                    I  Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-02-06 13:12:22.027 12742-12769 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.a4you                    W  Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2024-02-06 13:12:22.027 12742-12769 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.a4you                    W  Failed to initialize 101010-2 format, error = EGL_SUCCESS
2024-02-06 13:12:22.490 12742-12769 Gralloc4                com.example.a4you                    I  mapper 4.x is not supported
2024-02-06 13:12:22.566 12742-12769 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.a4you                    E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2024-02-06 13:12:22.870 12742-12742 Choreographer           com.example.a4you                    I  Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-02-06 13:12:22.877 12742-12760 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.a4you                    I  Davey! duration=1671ms; Flags=1, FrameTimelineVsyncId=154357, IntendedVsync=7636667470702, Vsync=7637434137338, InputEventId=0, HandleInputStart=7637442748660, AnimationStart=7637442823760, PerformTraversalsStart=7637443618360, DrawStart=7638076272260, FrameDeadline=7636684137368, FrameInterval=7637440573060, FrameStartTime=16666666, SyncQueued=7638090970860, SyncStart=7638095215360, IssueDrawCommandsStart=7638098793860, SwapBuffers=7638320194360, FrameCompleted=7638343706560, DequeueBufferDuration=287200, QueueBufferDuration=1606600, GpuCompleted=7638342711760, SwapBuffersCompleted=7638343706560, DisplayPresentTime=0, CommandSubmissionCompleted=7638320194360,
2024-02-06 13:12:27.903 12742-12781 ProfileInstaller        com.example.a4you                    D  Installing profile for com.example.a4you
2024-02-06 13:13:04.239 12742-12742 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.a4you                    D  Compat change id reported: 147798919; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
2024-02-06 13:13:05.322 12742-12742 Choreographer           com.example.a4you                    I  Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2024-02-06 13:13:05.692 12742-12769 OpenGLRenderer          com.example.a4you                    E  Unable to match the desired swap behavior.
2024-02-06 13:13:29.896 12742-12742 Compatibil...geReporter com.example.a4you                    D  Compat change id reported: 78294732; UID 10193; state: ENABLED
2024-02-06 13:13:30.211 12742-12742 WindowOnBackDispatcher  com.example.a4you                    W  sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@65238d3

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.a4you

import ...

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    // Firebase authentication instance
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    // Activity result launcher for Google Sign-In
    private lateinit var signInLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        // Check if the user is already signed in
        val currentUser = firebaseAuth.currentUser
        if (currentUser != null) {
            // User is already signed in, redirect to HomeActivity
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
            finish() // Finish MainActivity to prevent returning to it when pressing back
            return // Exit onCreate method
        }

        //Initialize the signInLauncher
        signInLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // If the result is OK, process the Google Sign-In
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(result.data)
                try {
                    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                    if (account != null) {
                        // Sign in with Google
                        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case where the Google account is null
                        Toast.makeText(this, "User account not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    // Handle ApiException
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Google sign in failed: ${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        // storing ID of the button
        // in a variable
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        val button1 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button1)
        val button0 = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button0)

        // operations to be performed
        // when user tap on the button
        button?.setOnClickListener()
        {
            // displaying a toast message
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, R.string.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, LoginActivity::class.java))
        }
        button0?.setOnClickListener()
        {
            // displaying a toast message
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, R.string.message0, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val signInIntent = getGoogleSignInIntent() // Obtain the signInIntent here
            signInLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
        }
        button1?.setOnClickListener()
        {
            // displaying a toast message
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, R.string.message1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }

    // Function to create Google Sign-In intent
    private fun getGoogleSignInIntent(): Intent {
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
        return mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
    }

    // Function to sign in with Google
    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Google sign in success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    // Proceed to the next activity or perform other actions
                    startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, HomeActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Google sign in failed: ${task.exception?.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some logs or errors from the logcat.

Comment: @KumarBibek Added logs from LogCat. I hope that helps.

Comment: There is too much output there and I cannot spot the issue at first glance. However, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle). It's a working solution.